# Label not printing in a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, confusion-matrix

I have a confusion matrix that I want to plot out instead of just print and I took the code from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html).

Here is the function that I took with some very slight modification.

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, round(cm[i, j],4)*100,
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
```

When I try to plot the figure using `plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes=['Front', 'Left', 'Rear', 'Right'],normalize=True,title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')`

I am getting this figure
 [image: Image1]

As you can see, the value for predicted and true label for left is missing. When I try this without normalization, everything seems to be working and I can see the actual number of predicted vs true label.

I am using python 3.5.3 and running the code on Jupyter Notebook 5.0.0. What could be causing this problem?

**EDIT**

The cm(confusion matrix) prior to the function call is

```
cm =   np.array([[20633,   219,   357,   118],
       [  136,   340,   199,     0],
       [   49,    10, 15536,    67],
       [  270,     2,   196,   353]])
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes=['Front', 'Left', 'Rear', 'Right'],normalize=True,title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')
```

Comment: The problem is that this is not reproducible. How can anyone know why this value is missing without having a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: Perhaps the left/left combination is set to NaN? As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest says, without the actual call to your function with arguments (data, params), its impossible to know why it does have this beahviour.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the comments. I hope now it is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is actually there. It's just white on some almost-white background, such that it is hard to see. I changed the gamma of the original image a bit, to make it visible:

[image]

You may want to change the threshold for making the text white to a larger number. E.g.

```
thresh = cm.max() / 1.4
```

results in the image as expected:

[image]